# Proof involving the spectral radius and the Jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, spectral-radius

> Let $A$ be a square matrix. Show that if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} A^{n} = 0$$ then $\rho(A) < 1$, where $\rho(A)$ denotes the *spectral radius* of $A$.
>
> Hint: Use the Jordan canonical form.

I am self-studying and have been working through a few linear algebra exercises. I'm struggling a bit in applying the hint to this problem — I don't know where to start. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This follows from $A^n v = \lambda^n v$. The other direction is straighforward using the Jordan form.

Comment: Any mention of the field one is working over?

Comment: The entries are allowed to be complex.

Answer (score 9):

You don't really need Jordan canonical form.  If $\rho(A) \ge 1$, $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| \ge 1$.  That eigenvalue has an eigenvector $v$.  Then $A^n v = \lambda^n v$, so $\|A^n v\| = |\lambda|^n \|v\| \ge \|v\|$ does not go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, which is impossible if $A^n \to 0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$A=PJP^{-1} \\
J=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & * & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 
0& \lambda_2 & * & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 
...&...&...&...&....&....&....\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0&...&\lambda_n \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where each $*$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Prove by induction that 
$$J^m=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1^m & \star & \star & \star & \star & ... & \star \\ 
0& \lambda_2^m & \star  & \star  & \star  & ... & \star  \\ 
...&...&...&...&....&....&....\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0&...&\lambda_n^m \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the $\star$s represent numbers, that is $J^m$ is an upper triangular matrix 
with the $m$^th powers of the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

**Note** The above claim for $J^m$ is not fully using that $J$ is a Jordan cannonical form. It only uses that $J$ is upper triangular.

Comment: So, $A^{m} = PJ^{m}P^{-1}$. If I can show what you're asking by induction, would the limit of $J^{m} = 0$? I'm sure it is because the diagonal entries are less than one, right?

Comment: @mXdX Well, that is the point. First $$\lim_m J^m= \lim_m P^{-1} A^m P =0$$ Now, since $\lim J^m=0$ you can deduce that the diagonal entries converge to zero, meaning $\lambda_j^m \to 0$. This implies that $|\lambda_j |<1$

Comment: I understand now. Thanks. So I would have to show, like you said, that the diagonal entries of $J^{m}$ are the $m$th powers of the eigenvalues.